# C++ error using Xcode

Tags: c++

I get an error on my code below in the else: control reaches end of non-void function?

```
double arrival(double x){

    x=temp->sim_time;
    e=temp->eventtype;

    insert_nextevent((x+ (-log(rand())/lamda)), 'A');

    if(server ==0){
        server =1;
        insert_nextevent((x +(-log(rand())/mu)), 'D');
    }

    else{

            numqueue++;
    }

}

double departure(double x){

    x=temp->sim_time;
    e=temp->eventtype;

    if(numqueue==0){
            server =1;
    }
    else {
            numqueue--;
            insert_nextevent((x+ (-log(rand())/mu)), 'D');
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed to return a value, what's unclear about that error?

Comment: Why are you even taking an input parameter if the first thing your function does is to overwrite it?

Comment: Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Is that really your question? The answer is: Yes you do get an error.

Comment: how? can you modify it please

Comment: I am coding M/M/1 queue system

Comment: do you know what it means for a function to return a value?

Comment: btw i am not trying to be sarcastic with the last comment, but trying to get this going somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the basics of C++ (or programming). When a function is declared with a return type, it must return a value. Functions can be declared void, as well. In that case you do not return a value. eg;

```
  void myFuncA(aType aParam);
  int myFuncB(aType aParam);
```

The first function returns no values, the second must return an int. Your code above is of the second form, so it must have a return statement with a value of the correct type.